# Return multiple replacements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple different text strings I need to replace on the client side.

Let's say I want to replace "Red Apple" with "Orange Orange" and "Sad Cat" with "Happy Dog".

I've been trying to extend [this question](http://jQuery%20if%20div%20contains%20this%20text,%20replace%20that%20part%20of%20the%20text) to handle multiple replacements.

```
$("#container h3 a").text(function () {
  return $(this).text().replace("Red Apple", "Orange Orange"); 
  return $(this).text().replace("Sad Cat", "Happy Dog");
});
```

I'm finding that only the first replacement is returned.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to return multiples, not getting the desired result like this either.

```
return {
  ...
}
```

Rationale for this not being [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783):  Note that I am not trying to replace just Apples but also Cats.

Comment: Your second return is never reached since you have already returned off the function the first time.

Comment: @dave I have added my rationale for this not being a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your code reaches a `return` statement, no code after that will be processed. `return` literally returns control to the caller code.

As **[MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)**:

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
>   be returned to the function caller.

You can deal with issues like this in a couple of ways:

1. You could build up a value and then return that value:

   ```
   $("#container h3 a").text(function () {

     // Work on your return value as much as you want
     var retVal = $(this).text();
     retVal = retVal.replace("Red Apple", "Orange Orange");
     retVal = retVal.replace("Sad Cat", "Happy Dog");

     return retVal;  // And then return it (just once)
   });
   ```

   **Note that there is absolutely nothing wrong with this approach as it is easy to read and understand.**
2. Or, in this case, you can just chain the `.replace()` calls because each time you call `.replace()` it returns a new string that you can then call `.replace()` on. The final string will be returned as the value that the original `return` actually sends back:

   ```
   $("#container h3 a").text(function () {
     return $(this).text().replace("Red Apple", "Orange Orange")
              .replace("Sad Cat", "Happy Dog");
   });
   ```

   **Note that this approach accomplishes the exact same thing, but it is more compact, precise and eliminates the need for a temporary storage variable.**

Answer (score 4):

Your first `return` ends the function. The second `return` is never reached.

But you can chain the replacements.

```
$("#container h3 a").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Red Apple", "Orange Orange").replace("Sad Cat", "Happy Dog");
});
```

Comment: Yes. Worth adding that the reason @AllInOne's code is breaking is because a function effectively ends once it `return`s.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do it by calling replace twice in one return statement.

```
return $(this).text().replace("Red Apple", "Orange Orange").replace("Sad Cat", "Happy Dog");
```